# Change color of overlayed bar graphs ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've plotted two bar graphs on top of each other using the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)


x = c("type1", "type2", "type3")
y1 = c("1","2","3")
y2 = c("2","3","4")

to_plot <- data.frame(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2)
melted<-melt(to_plot, id="x")

ggplot() + geom_bar(data=melted,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable),stat="identity",position = "identity", alpha=.3)
```

This gave me the following output:
[image]

Is there anyway I can change the color of the bar graphs? For example, I would like the y1 graph to be the same grey as the background

Comment: Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Okay. I've made a reproducible example @Masoud

Comment: `scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("y1" = "gray", "y2" = "orange"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(data=melted,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable),
                    stat="identity",position = "identity", alpha=.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#955599", "#E63F00"))
```

You can now play with the palette (-;

Comment: :D :D Thank you! Play, I shall

Comment: `myplot +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray", "lightblue")) + 
  theme_gray()` If you don't want to play